# PHP Curl from remote country shared server too slow - getFlightInfo() reason is unclear to me:

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP Curl from remote country shared host it takes me very long time to get web page contents (~3 seconds average time).

When I run the same simple code to get the file content (HTTP Get) it takes third time (~1 second).

My questions are:

a) why? (I don't see a DNS problem here - please correct me if I'm wrong.)

b) Is there something I can do about it, except from moving to a host within the same country... (?)

Here is the PHP Curl code, followed by curl_getinfo() output of remote country and same country results:

```
$mainUrl = 'www.example.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mainUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
```

Test results:

```
Remote country web server       Same country                curl_getinfo()

200                             200                         http_code
402                             402                         header_size
445                             445                         request_size
-1                              -1                          filetime
0                               0                           ssl_verify_result
0                               0                           redirect_count
3.031631                        1.326                       total_time
3.20E-05                        0                           namelookup_time
3.60E-05                        0                           connect_time
8.10E-05                        0                           pretransfer_time
6590                            7096                        size_upload
470296                          370232                      size_download
155129                          279209                      speed_download
2173                            5351                        speed_upload
470296                          370232                      download_content_length
6590                            7096                        upload_content_length
0.162921                        0.031                       starttransfer_time
0                               0                           redirect_time
```

Comment: What does getFligthInfo() do? this can be lots of different things from a slow connection between you and the host to getFlightInfo taking longer to run on the host. So if you can show us getFlightInfo that might help.

Comment: did you try a traceroute from the servers to the target?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, changed getFlightInfo() to curl_getinfo().

Comment: I will try to find out how to call traceroute from my shared web server (if someone know please let me know), thanks I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Couldn't trace route from the server, if anyone can suggest alternarives to switching host server...